# Sveltekit no intellisense for generated $types module | WebStorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm, sveltekit

Writing without no mini repro just to ask maybe there is some setting in WebStorm to parse intellisense from automatically generated `./$types` by SvelteKit.

Just to clarify everything is done exactly by SvelteKit's docs. Using `satisfies LayoutLoad` and .etc

Answer (score 0):

Those types are generated automatically when you run the project in dev mode:

```bash
npm run dev
```

Run this command and let it be in the background. It will generate the types and WebStorm should pick them up automatically.
You can adjust this command to the package manager you use (`npm`, `yarn`, `pnpm`, etc).

There might also be an option to tell WebStorm to have this command running in the background but, if there is, I don't know how to configure it.

Comment: The types are being generated successfully, it's just not being picked up by Webstorm :/

Comment: Oh, I see. That's weird. The types are linked to your `tsconfig.json` throught the `extends` clause. Maybe you can make WebStorm to point to the extended file too?